# Hacer un insert en dos tablas difentes

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

hola tengo una duda de como realizar un insert a dos tablas diferentes con php teniendo foreign key, esto en un solo formulario que se tiene...

```
CREATE TABLE validador(id_registro int not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,id int not null, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES usuario (id) on UPDATE CASCADE on DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE encuesta(id_encuesta int not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, id_registro int not null,id int not null, FOREIGN KEY (id_registro) REFERENCES validador(id_registro) on UPDATE CASCADE on DELETE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES usuario (id) on UPDATE CASCADE on DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Hola, Pedro. Para poder ayudarte, ¿Tienes algún código que has intentado hacer? Lo que describes arriba son las DDL de las tablas, lo cual está bien, pero necesitamos más información.

Comment: Muestra algún código que ya hallas hecho o consultado, la verdad es muy difícil solucionar algo que aun no has intentado.

Comment: un ejemplo muy sencillo es hacer esto... pero como tengo dos tablas no tengo una idea de como realizarlo teniendo en cuenta que los ids llaves primerias y secundarias tienen que ser el mismo                    INSERT INTO encuesta_responsable(id,id_jefe,id_nomina ) VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO encuesta_empleado(id,id_registro ) VALUES (1,1);